# Getting 'sorry we cannot take you to this destination at this time' message when using Deeplink to go to one to one chat in MS Teams on android device

Tags: android, microsoft-teams, deep-linking

Getting 'Sorry we cannot take you to this destination at this time' message when using Deep link to go to one-to-one chat in MS Teams on an Android device.

I am using the deep link as 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=${userPrincipleName}&source=abc' to create a new one-to-one chat or open an existing one-to-one chat.

this works fine on iOS/desktop. But when accessing on an Android device it gives a popup as 'Sorry we cannot take you to this destination at this time'.

Is there any change in the URL for the deep link?

Thank you!

Comment: There is already a bug raised for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this bug? @Prasad-MSFT

Comment: This fix is being rolled out internally. Once the fix is publicly available, we will inform in this thread.

Comment: The issue is fixed as of version "1416/1.0.0.2024032904". Please do verify.